# Can I make my configure script define the VERSION variable from a file instead of being hard coded?

Tags: git, version, autotools, configure

I'm diving into autotools and have successfully gotten most of my build process down, but I've recently hit a snag keeping track of the `VERSION` variable. We develop as a group using git, and currently have a system in place that bakes part of the git commit hash into a version string that is part of our library. This way, when we have compiled code it's easy to check which commit it was compiled from. For example if we run `mything --version` it prints `0.1.1.1f034b7`.

My current solution to do this with autotools involves having a `version.sh` script in the repository that probes git for the commit hash and outputs the version string as shown above. Then in `configure.ac` I've got

`AC_INIT([example],
        [m4_esyscmd([./version.sh])],
        [myphonyaddress@me.com],
        [],
        [amazingcode.com])`

With this I can run `autoreconf -i`, generate a `configure` script and do the usual `./configure && make && make install`. By runing `./configure`, a file in the project called `version.cc` is created from `version.cc.in`, by substituting `@VERSION@` with the version string I want. This is where the function relevant to `mything --version` resides.

Though, this works, I dislike the fact that every time I make a commit, I have to rerun `autoreconf -i`, because with each commit made, the `configure` script gets out of date.

What I'd like to do is have the generated `configure` script know that the `VERSION` variable isn't some hard coded string. Instead, I could have `version.sh` save the version string to an untracked file that the `configure` script would read to determine what `VERSION` should be.

Is this possible without *too* much macro witchcraft? I want to set the version stuff up once and forget about it. I'm open to alternative solutions as well, but it'd be nice not to require other developers to install autotools in order to contribute.

---

I know there's some strong opinions on automake and build systems in general. Please refrain from telling me how much you hate autotools. I'm pretty new and still learning, but I honestly don't think it's bad at all. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I've done something like this before.  I left `VERSION` a static number in `configure.ac`, except when it needed to be changed.  As you've discovered, commit-by-commit changing of the revision number gets tedious very quickly.

IIRC, what I remember settling on was adding a file that had the version info as an [`EXTRA_DIST`](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Basics-of-Distribution.html) file (so it was bundled with the tarball).  In order to make that file I had another file as a [phony target](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html) which grabbed the revision info from the VCS (if it detected it was using one, opposed to being an extracted source tarball) and copied itself (or not, if there was no VCS) to the `EXTRA_DIST` file.  No macro witchcraft was involved at all.

So if `version` is the `EXTRA_DIST` target, something like:

```
mydef_version=`cat version`
AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED([VERSION_GIT],["$mydef_version"])
```

in `configure.ac` would set up a define for your C++ translation unit:

```
const char version_info[] = VERSION "." VERSION_GIT;
```

The `EXTRA_DIST` file could also be a self contained translation unit too that just has version info.

I was using `rpmbuild` on my CI server which requires a tarball to build instead of a checked-out repo, so basically the first stage of the build was basically `autoreconf...; ./configure...; make dist;`  and the second stage was `rpmbuild -ta tarball;`.

Comment: Thank you for replying! I thought I was going to get another tumbleweed badge. I like the idea of the phony target to generate an ```EXTRA_DIST file```. I was thinking I could achieve that through a post-commit git hook, but I think your idea is better.
Just having the ```EXTRA_DIST``` file doesn't quite solve my issue though. I would still need to run ```autoreconf``` for the ```configure``` script to know the latest full version and git hash string. Ideally ```configure``` would know to grab ```VERSION``` (or whatever variable) from the EXTRA_DIST file without ```autoreconf```.

Comment: @jonthalpy did you ever find a solution to your version problem that didn't require you to rerun `autoreconf` and `configure`?

Comment: @houtanb unfortunately not, I've just learned to live with it.